# ActionScript 3.0: Sharing attributes in classes

Tags: actionscript-3, class, actionscript, data-members

Would anyone be able to help me out with this research for my actionscript class? Ive been asked to research the relationships between classes but having trouble understanding it.

Within my code, the class A creates an instance of class B inside it, storing the instantiated B in a variable in class A so that class A can access data members (attributes) and methods from class B.

How could I create a link in B so that it can also access information about class A?

Answer (score 2):

Add an argument to the constructor of class `B`:

```
public function B(a:A)
```

And a relevant property:

```
private var _a:A;
```

`B` should look something like this:

```
public class B
{
    private var _a:A;

    public function B(a:A)
    {
        _a = a;
    }
}
```

And when you create an instance of `B` within `A`, send a reference to `A` along with it:

```
var b:B = new B(this);
```

Within `B` you'll be able to make use of `A`'s visible members via `_a`.

Answer (score 0):

you again ! Same question !!
"so that class A can access data members (attributes) and methods from class B."

If Class B extends Class A then class A can access the public methods and attributes of B using the keyword "super". Like if class B has the function "myFunc", class A can access it using super.myFunc();

Read this : http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2009/08/10/understanding-as3-super-statement/

Comment: Haha Its not entirely the same question! But thank you, Ive just read through that link and its becoming clearer.